# Xamarin Debug -> iPhone, Failed to compile the generated registrar code. (MT4109)

Tags: ios, debugging, build, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I'm trying to build up my App for testing on Device.
I'm facing an huge problem with the debugging:

- The device is registered
- I'm using a Dev Provisioning Profile
- If I build and publish "release" no problem occurs
- If I build Debug / iPhone I get:

/---PATH----/MTOUCH: Error MT4109: Failed to compile the generated registrar code. Please file a bug report at http://bugzilla.xamarin.com (MT4109) (---PROJECT NAME---)

Taking a closer look to the logs:

```
Process exited with code 1, command:
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang  -gdwarf-2 -I/Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/9.0.1.29/SDKs/MonoTouch.iphoneos.sdk/usr/include -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS9.0.sdk -Qunused-arguments -miphoneos-version-min=8.0 -arch arm64 -c -DDEBUG  -o /---PATH---/obj/iPhone/Debug/mtouch-cache/registrar.arm64.o -Wno-receiver-forward-class -x objective-c++ -fno-caret-diagnostics -fno-diagnostics-fixit-info -
    <stdin>:3804:35: error: type name does not allow storage class to be specified
    <stdin>:3804:32: warning: declaration does not declare anything [-Wmissing-declarations]
```

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

If someone stumbles over this problem as I did:

Try adding --noregistrar to the additional mtouch arguments in the project's options (iPhone Build page).

Comment: Unclear what you're asking, please add an image or some code related with your problem.

Comment: My comment is related to the problem above and should fix it

Comment: Images are helpful and for clarity